# Add filter to the end of the post

Tags: posts, filters

I have a function which is used to display a video,
I want this video to be shown after the post,
It should display the video when the post ends.

I have added filter to it, but then too, the video is shown before the post.

Here is the filter which I am using:

```
function append_the_video($content) {
            global $post;
            $content .= youtube_video();
            return $content;
            }
    add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_video');
```

edited 
entire function

```
<?php
function youtube_video()
{
?>
<div class="post">

<?php 

$newvar = urlencode(get_the_title());
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
$rss = fetch_rss('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q='.$newvar.'&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2');
    $maxitems = get_option('novideos');

    $items =is_array($rss->items) ? array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems) : '' ;
                            ?>
<ul>
<?php if (empty($items)) {echo "No current video uploads by ".get_the_title();}
else foreach ( $items as $item ) : ?>
<?php
$youtubeid = strchr($item['link'],'='); 
$youtubeid = substr($youtubeid,1);
?>

<p>Latest Videos of <b><?php the_title(); ?>:</b></p>
<br>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="320" height="265">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $youtubeid ?>&hl=en&fs=1" />
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $youtubeid ?>&hl=en&fs=1" width="320" height="265">
<!--<![endif]-->
<p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $youtubeid ?>">View movie&raquo;</a></p>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php

}
function append_the_video($content) {
        global $post;
        $content .= youtube_video();
        return $content;
        }
add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_video');

?>
```

Comment: are you sure your youtube_video() function is returning a string and not printing the video?

Comment: @Daniel Dvorkin yaa you are right, its directly printing the value, its not returning the value, so how can I append it to the post end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

1) Edit your youtube_video() function so it return a string instead of printing the code

2) The easiest way... if you can edit your theme, place the youtube_video() call after showing your post content

Edit:

```
<?php
function youtube_video()
{

$ret = "";

$ret .= "<div class='post'>";


$newvar = urlencode(get_the_title());
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
$rss = fetch_rss('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/videos?q='.$newvar.'&client=ytapi-youtube-search&v=2');
    $maxitems = get_option('novideos');

    $items =is_array($rss->items) ? array_slice($rss->items, 0, $maxitems) : '' ;

$ret .= "<ul>";

if (empty($items)) {$ret .= " 'No current video uploads by '.get_the_title()";}
else foreach ( $items as $item ) :
$youtubeid = strchr($item['link'],'='); 
$youtubeid = substr($youtubeid,1);

$ret .= "<p>Latest Videos of <b>" . get_the_title() . ":</b></p>";
$ret .= "<br>";
$ret .= "<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='320' height='265'>";
$ret .= "<param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $youtubeid ."&hl=en&fs=1' />";
$ret .= "<!--[if !IE]>-->";
$ret .= "<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $youtubeid ."&hl=en&fs=1' width='320' height='265'>";
$ret .= "<!--<![endif]-->";
$ret .= "<p><a href='http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $youtubeid ."'>View movie&raquo;</a></p>";
$ret .= "<!--[if !IE]>-->";
$ret .= "</object>";
$ret .= "<!--<![endif]-->";
$ret .= "</object>";
$ret .= "</li>";

endforeach; 
$ret .= "</ul>";
$ret .= "</div>";

return $ret;
}

?>
```

Comment: Daniel Dvorkin how do I make my function to return the value instead of printing?

Comment: I edited my answer with the code

Answer (score 2):

Try containing the content and the video inside different div's:

```
function append_the_video($content) {
        global $post;
        return '<div class="content_inner">'.$content.'</div><div class="content_video">'. youtube_video().'</div>';
}
add_filter('the_content', 'append_the_video');
```

Comment: the code which you gave doesn't helps me, because my function is not returning any value, its directly printing it,

Comment: sorry there was an `=` sign in the return, i removed it, and post your youtube_video() function code so will see just how to change it to return value instead of echoing it.

Comment: check my question

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a simple way to add an argument so it only appends the 'youtube' function to the_content on a specific post_type?